# In polars, nested when-then-otherwise gives unexpected behavior in groupby / window context

Tags: dataframe, python-polars, rust-polars

I have a custom expression to wrap around the "rank" expression to ignore nulls.

```py
def rank(_exp,method='average',reverse=False):
    #Fill nans so as not to affect ranking
    fill = -np.Inf if reverse else np.Inf
    tmp = pl.when(_exp.is_not_null()).then(_exp).otherwise(fill).rank(reverse=reverse,method=method)
    #Plug nans back in
    exp = pl.when(_exp.is_not_null()).then(tmp).otherwise(_exp)
    return exp
```

For simple dataframe with nulls, this gives expected results:

```
df_with_nan = pl.DataFrame({'X': np.where(np.isin(np.arange(10),[1,3]),np.NaN,np.arange(10)), 'G1':np.array(['A']*5 + ['B']*5), 'G2':np.array(['C','D']*5)})
df_with_null = df_with_nan.fill_nan(None)

print(df_with_null.with_columns(rank(pl.col(['X'])).suffix('_rnk')))

shape: (10, 4)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ X    ┆ G1  ┆ G2  ┆ X_rnk │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ f64  ┆ str ┆ str ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 0.0  ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ A   ┆ D   ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ A   ┆ D   ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ... ┆ ... ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6.0  ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ 5.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7.0  ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ 6.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8.0  ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ 7.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9.0  ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ 8.0   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

The window context seems to jumble order:

```py
print(df_with_null.with_columns(rank(pl.col(['X'])).over(['G1','G2']).suffix('_rnk')))
shape: (10, 4)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ X    ┆ G1  ┆ G2  ┆ X_rnk │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ f64  ┆ str ┆ str ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 0.0  ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ A   ┆ D   ┆ 1.5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ A   ┆ D   ┆ 1.5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ... ┆ ... ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6.0  ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7.0  ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8.0  ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9.0  ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ 3.0   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

Similarly, groupby context seems to jumble the order

```
print(df_with_null.groupby(['G1','G2']).agg([pl.col(['X']),rank(pl.col(['X'])).suffix('_rnk')]).explode(['X','X_rnk']))

shape: (10, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ G1  ┆ G2  ┆ X    ┆ X_rnk │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str ┆ f64  ┆ f64   │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ A   ┆ C   ┆ 0.0  ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A   ┆ C   ┆ 2.0  ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A   ┆ C   ┆ 4.0  ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A   ┆ D   ┆ null ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ... ┆ ... ┆ ...  ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ D   ┆ 7.0  ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ D   ┆ 9.0  ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ C   ┆ 6.0  ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ C   ┆ 8.0  ┆ 2.0   │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Through process of elimination, it seems to be the line in the my rank function that "plugs nans back in", but unsure why, and also unsure of alternative ways to implement this functionality.

Comment: This solution may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73252912/how-to-set-masked-values-within-each-group-in-groupby-context-using-py-polars

Answer (score 1):

Since `NaN` and `null` values can create headaches with calculations, I recommend the following:

1. Partition your dataset into two: one dataset with `NaN`/`null` values, the other without.
2. Run your calculations on the dataset without the `NaN`/`null` values.
3. Concatenate the two datasets.

For example, using your `df_with_nan` dataset, we can use the [`partition_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.partition_by.html#polars.DataFrame.partition_by) function to split your dataset into two.

```py
part_df_dict = (
    df_with_nan
    .with_column(pl.col('X').is_nan().alias('X_nan'))
    .partition_by('X_nan', as_dict=True)
)
part_df_dict
```

```
{False: shape: (8, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ X   ┆ G1  ┆ G2  ┆ X_nan │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ f64 ┆ str ┆ str ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0 ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.0 ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.0 ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6.0 ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7.0 ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8.0 ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9.0 ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ false │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┘,
True: shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ X   ┆ G1  ┆ G2  ┆ X_nan │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ f64 ┆ str ┆ str ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ NaN ┆ A   ┆ D   ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN ┆ A   ┆ D   ┆ true  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┘}
```

Next, run your calculations on the dataset without the `NaN` values:

```py
part_df_dict[False] = (
    part_df_dict[False]
    .with_column(pl.col('X').rank().over(['G1', 'G2']).alias('X_rank'))
)
part_df_dict[False]
```

```
shape: (8, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┬────────┐
│ X   ┆ G1  ┆ G2  ┆ X_nan ┆ X_rank │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ f64 ┆ str ┆ str ┆ bool  ┆ f32    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 1.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0 ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 2.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.0 ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 3.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.0 ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ false ┆ 1.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6.0 ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 1.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7.0 ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ false ┆ 2.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8.0 ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 2.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9.0 ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ false ┆ 3.0    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Then use the [`concat`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html#polars.concat) function along with `how="diagonal"` to concatenate the results together.  You can also sort if you'd like.

```py
result = (
    pl.concat(list(part_df_dict.values()), how='diagonal')
    .sort(['G1', 'G2'])
)
result
```

```
shape: (10, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┬────────┐
│ X   ┆ G1  ┆ G2  ┆ X_nan ┆ X_rank │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ f64 ┆ str ┆ str ┆ bool  ┆ f32    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 1.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0 ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 2.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.0 ┆ A   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 3.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN ┆ A   ┆ D   ┆ true  ┆ null   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN ┆ A   ┆ D   ┆ true  ┆ null   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6.0 ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 1.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8.0 ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ false ┆ 2.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.0 ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ false ┆ 1.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7.0 ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ false ┆ 2.0    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9.0 ┆ B   ┆ D   ┆ false ┆ 3.0    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┴────────┘
```

The result is much cleaner.  And you're assured that the `NaN`/`null` values will not affect your results.  An added bonus is that your code is easier to follow.